Computing spectrum of very simple Schrödinger operator
I asked this question recently on a thread in math stack exchange, but with no real answers suggested. I think this is a relatively simple variation on the classical free Laplacian spectrum, so I assume there is a reference regarding this that I did not know to find.
I am consider the a discrete Schrodinger operator on $\mathbb{Z}$ with potential values $v(n)= V\cdot \delta_{0,n}$ for some $V\in \mathbb{R}$. More explicitly, $H_V:\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})\to \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ given by
$$ (H_V\psi)(n)= \psi(n+1)+\psi(n-1)+v(n)\cdot \psi(n) \quad \text{for all} \quad \psi \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}) \quad \text{and} \quad n\in \mathbb{Z}, $$
where $v(n)= V\cdot \delta_{0,n}$ for some $V\in \mathbb{R}$. If $V=0$, then this is just the adjacency operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, and $\text{spec}(H_V)=[-2,2]$. But even when $V\neq 0$, this is still a one dimensional perturbation of the adjacency operator. It is relatively simple to show that if $\vert V\vert>2$, then $\text{spec}(H_V) \supsetneq [-2,2]$.
Does anyone of somewhere where this simple question is tackled?

I do not know the reference, if you just want to know the answer, here it is.

For odd sequences nothing changes: $H_V$ has absolutely continuous spectrum $[-2,2]$ on the space $\ell^2_{\operatorname{odd}}$ of odd sequences, with (generalised) eigenvectors $s_\lambda(n) = \sin(\lambda n)$ and (generalised) eigenvalues $2 \cos \lambda$.
For even sequences we have (generalised) eigenvectors $$c_\lambda(n) = \cos(\lambda |n| + \arctan\tfrac{V}{2\sin \lambda}),$$ with (generalised) eigenvalues $2 \cos \lambda$, where $\lambda \in [0, \pi]$, which correspond to continuous spectrum $[-2, 2]$. If $V > 0$, then there is additionally a (regular) eigenvector $$v(n) = \frac{e^{-\lambda |n|}}{\sqrt{\coth \lambda}},$$ where $\sinh \lambda = \frac{V}{2}$, corresponding to the eigenvalue $2 \cosh \lambda = \sqrt{4 + V^2}$. Similarly, if $V < 0$, then there is a (regular) eigenvector $$v(n) = \frac{(-1)^n e^{-\lambda |n|}}{\sqrt{\coth \lambda}},$$ where $\sinh \lambda = -\frac{V}{2}$, corresponding to the eigenvalue $-2 \cosh \lambda = -\sqrt{4 + V^2}$.

I suppose there is a more elegant way to make all of this rigorous, for example:

a perturbation argument (continuous spectrum does not change, one only needs to find the discrete spectrum);

a generalised eigenvector expansion argument ($\exp(t H_V)$ is a Carleman oeprator and so it has a generalised eigenvector expansion, with all generalised eigenvectors bounded, and the above calculation describes all bounded generalised eigenvectors);


but one can simply write down the eigenvector expansion:
$$ \begin{aligned} \langle \phi, H_V \psi \rangle & = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \langle \phi, s_\lambda \rangle \cdot 2 \cos \lambda \cdot \langle s_\lambda, \psi \rangle d\lambda \\ & + \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \langle \phi, c_\lambda \rangle \cdot 2 \cos \lambda \cdot \langle c_\lambda, \psi \rangle d\lambda \\ & + \langle \phi, v \rangle \cdot (\pm \sqrt{4 + V^2}) \cdot \langle v, \psi \rangle .\end{aligned} $$
The above equation can be proved by direct integration, but this is a tedious exercise.

Bottom line: the spectrum (on $\ell^2_{\operatorname{odd}}$, and hence also on $\ell^2$) is

$[-2, 2]$ if $V = 0$;
$[-2, 2] \cup \{\sqrt{4 + V^2}\}$ if $V > 0$;
$[-2, 2] \cup \{-\sqrt{4 + V^2}\}$ if $V < 0$.


Thank you for your answer! What do you mean exactly by odd and even sequences?

A sequence $x(n)$ is odd if $x(-n)=-x(n)$ and even if $x(-n)=x(n)$. I guess this is not a standard terminology for sequences, sorry.
